# Choosing pg_fetch_row data types

Tags: php, postgresql, casting

When I use `pg_fetch_row` all the values are returned as "string". Is there any way (other than walking the array of returned values) to choose the type of some of the columns (for instance when I select an integer I want `42` not `"42"`) ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not... it always returns strings and you have to convert them yourself.

Since PHP implicitly converts when needed, usually not that much of a problem but if you need it... you'll have to do it manually.